# How Scotty make an Applicative constructor

Tags: haskell, applicative, scotty

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative

import Data.Monoid
import Data.String

import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger

import Web.Scotty

data FullName = FullName { firstName :: String, lastName :: String }

lastFirst :: FullName -> String
lastFirst fn = lastName fn ++ ", " ++ firstName fn

main = scotty 3000 $ do
    middleware logStdoutDev

    get "/lastfirst/:fn/:ln" $ do
        fullName <- FullName <$> param "fn" <*> param "ln"
        html $ fromString (lastFirst fullName)
```

You may notice that the last part of the code use applicative function to construct a record, can someone explain why it shouldn't be created as usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `param "fn"` is *not* a `String`, but an `ActionM` which produces a `String`. We don't want to store the action inside `FullName`, we want to run the action, take its result, and store that.

We could run the actions as follows

```
get "/lastfirst/:fn/:ln" $ do
    fn <- param "fn"
    ln <- param "ln"
    let fullName = FullName fn ln
    html $ fromString (lastFirst fullName)
```

but the applicative syntax is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can we construct a new record by FullName <$> "John" <*> "Hanks" ? Why?

Comment: @nobody No, just use `FullName "John" "Hanks"` since those are strings, not actions. Use `<$>/<*>` only when you have actions around, and you need to execute them to get their result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!